# INotifyCollectionChanged and Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone

To solve the lack of `CollectionViewSource` on WinRT, Android, iPhone I decided to write an alternative that would exist in the view model.

This works fine on Windows Phone but on WinRT the `CollectionChanged` event is never anything other than `null` so the collection never loads (unless you navigate back from the page and then to it again but that's because the view models are stored in state).

The source code is here: https://gist.github.com/jamie94bc/6262479

Thanks!

**In the View Model**

```
private ObservableCollection<Task> _col;
private CollectionViewSource<Task> _colView;

public ObservableCollection<Task> Col {
    get { return _col ?? (_col = new ObservableCollection<T>()); }
}

public CollectionViewSource<Task> ColView {
    get { return _colView ?? (_colView = new CollectionViewSource<Task>(this.Col, x => x.IsComplete, new SortDescription<Task>(x => x.Created))); } 
}
```

**In XAML**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ColView}"></ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer basically was to expose a view property (as an `ObservableCollection<T>`) on the `CollectionViewSource` implementation.

The `CollectionViewSource` then modifies the `View` rather implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `IEnumerable`.

It turns out `INotifyCollectionChanged` was actually replaced with `IObservableVector` in Windows 8, and during the early previews `ObservableCollection` didn't work at all - I presume there's something going on behind the scenes in Windows 8 which deals with `ObservableCollection`s but not `INotifyCollectionChanged`.